# How to authenticate Google Sites users on a Drupal site?

Tags: drupal-7, single-sign-on, openid, google-openid

So, I need to provide Single Sign On access to an existing Drupal 7 site for users of a second site built with Google Sites. The Drupal site has an existing user base which is separate from that of the Google Site’s users. The Google Site will have its own users, which should have access to both their site and the google site. I will be provided with Oauth2.0 configuration details to allow the Google Sites users to login authenticating against the Google Site as an IDP. So, the D7 site should only be accessible to the Drupal users and the google sites uses, not anyone with a google account.
I am assuming since the backend is google, that the site's users will be ultimately Google Users. The site uses "Oauth2.0 to Authenticate" other apps. Drupal has on [OpenID connect module](https://www.drupal.org/project/openid_connect) and I was wondering if the OpenID protocol would be used on top of the oauth2 credentials provided by the site admin? In essence, can I use this module to provide SSO access for the Google Sites users?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? You are building a new site on Drupal 7 and you want this to be accessed by only a set of users who have access to a given site that is built on Google site. If yes, who are the users of the Google site (can any Google user access it)? Who controls that Google site?